# Type inacurracy

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm trying to create `Entity Data Model`  using Visual Studio 2012 and Oracle 10g.
I'm getting this error:

> Error 1 Running transformation: The types of all properties in the
>   Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the
>   corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of
>   property 'QUARTAL_SEC_ID' on entity 'Model.QUARTAL' does not match the
>   type of property 'SEC_ID' on entity 'Model.SEC' in the referential
>   constraint 'FK_QUARTAL_SEC_ID'.

Indeed `sec_id` has `number(32)` and `quartal_sec_id` - `number(10)` in the database. I can't change it there. 
I have changed both types in mapping  details in `VS12` to `int32`. But it doesn't help.
Is it possible to solve this problem in VS12? Can I force it to accept different values in foreign keys?

I can't map number(10) (ORA) to decimal(VS) cause will get additional err:

> Error 2   Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.Decimal[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=,Scale=]' of
>   member 'QUARTAL_SEC_ID' in type 'Model.QUARTAL' is not compatible with
>   'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=10,Scale=0]'
>   of member 'QUARTAL_SEC_ID' in type 'Model.Store.QUARTAL'.

Comment: in your app config do you have anything set up for <oracle.dataaccess.client><settings>...?

Answer (score -1):

I am currently using EF 5 with Oracle and for number types we have our entity properties set as decimals.

This [article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/featLINQ.htm) outlines the data types.